# How do I get R to tell me which links are broken when downloading files?

Tags: r

I have a list of links to PDF files that looks like this:

```
df$urls <- c("http://www.frbsf.org/publications/economics/letter/2012/el2012-15.pdf", "http://research.stlouisfed.org/publications/es/11/ES1134.pdf", "http://www.frbsf.org/publications/economics/papers/2011/wp11-18bk.pdf", "https://www.minneapolisfed.org/research/sr/sr540.pdf", "brokenlink.pdf")
```

I have a script that downloads each of these files to a folder, which looks like this:

```
urls <- df$urls
for (url in urls) {
    tryCatch({download.file(url, paste0('~/Desktop/Dataset/Folder', basename(url)))}, error = function(e) {})
    }
```

However, some of the links don't work and I need to know which ones they are. Ideally, I would get an output that fills an empty vector with NA every time tryCatch encounters a broken link. In other words, in addition to downloading the files, I would get an output that looks like this:

```
urls <- c("http://www.frbsf.org/publications/economics/letter/2012/el2012-15.pdf", "http://research.stlouisfed.org/publications/es/11/ES1134.pdf", "http://www.frbsf.org/publications/economics/papers/2011/wp11-18bk.pdf", "https://www.minneapolisfed.org/research/sr/sr540.pdf", "brokenlink.pdf")
output <- c("", "", "", "", NA)
```

Does anyone know how I can do this? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. That just produces the following warning message: trying URL 'brokenlink.pdf'
Warning message:
In download.file(url, paste0("~/Desktop/Dataset/Folder", basename(url))) :
  URL 'brokenlink.pdf': status was 'Couldn't resolve host name'

Comment: I have about 150,000 entries to check so I need to know which ones are NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since dead links give a warning, not an error, we need to catch the warning. We also need to assign the output of the `tryCatch` block to keep track of the results:

```
out <- rep(NA, length(urls))
for (i in seq_along(urls)) {
  out[i] <- tryCatch(
    {download.file(urls[i], paste0('~/Desktop/', basename(urls[i])))}, 
    error = function(e) {},
    warning = function(w) {NA}
  )
}

out
# [1]  0  0  0  0 NA

which(is.na(out))
# [1] 5
```

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution using `map` and `safely` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
urls_list <- map(setNames(urls, urls), 
                    safely(~download.file(.x, paste0('~/Desktop/',basename(.x))))) 

Filter(function(x) is.null(x[['result']]), urls_list)
```

Output:

```
$brokenlink.pdf
$brokenlink.pdf$result
NULL

$brokenlink.pdf$error
<simpleError in download.file(.x, paste0(getwd(), "/", basename(.x))): scheme not supported in URL 'brokenlink.pdf'>
```

Comment: Or `urls_list %>% map("error") %>% compact()` at the end to make it `purrr` all the way.